# Duplicate Rows of Data Except 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table  CheckSheet_fault with tow columns  the data as follows

```
CheckSheet_No  |      Fault     |    

1                         A 
1                         B
1                         C
2                         A
2                         C
```

How Can I achieve the following results into destination table using SQL?

```
CheckSheet_No  |      Fault  1   |    Fault 2        |   Fault 3

1                         A             B                  C
2                         A             C
```

I can add maximum of 10 Fault columns in my destination table.My aim is to not duplicate the checksheet number.

Thanks
Cheers,
Rushir

Comment: is it mysql or sql server , can't be both

Comment: Hi there,Its SQL Server..I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this works

```
SELECT CheckSheet_No,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN Fault END) As Fault1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN Fault END) As Fault2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN Fault END) As Fault3
FROM
   (
   SELECT CheckSheet_No,Fault,
       Row_Number() Over(Partition By CheckSheet_No Order By Fault) as rn
   FROM CheckSheet_fault 
   ) Z
GROUP BY Z.CheckSheet_No
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5df8/3)

Comment: Wouldn't that get the counts?

Comment: morever using SUM was throwing error ... cannot use SUM with varchar operator

Comment: You are a genius! You saved my life! Thanks Hasan! That was a great help! Cheers,

Comment: @mhasan i think above will work but only for three columns if more then three we need to modify a query each time. instead of that we could use the below query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you have more then three columns.

```
CREATE Table  #table1  (CheckSheet_No int,Fault varchar(1))

    insert INTO #table1 values(1,'A')
    insert INTO #table1 values(1,'B')
    insert INTO #table1 values(1,'C')
    insert INTO #table1 values(2,'A')
    insert INTO #table1 values(2,'C')

    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols=stuff((
                SELECT ', ' + MAX(fault)
                FROM #table1
                group by fault
                order by fault
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '');

    SET @query = 'SELECT CheckSheet_No, ' + @cols + ' 
                from 
                 (
                       SELECT #table1.CheckSheet_No,Fault FROM #table1 
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                MAX(Fault)
                    for x.Fault in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p'

    execute sp_executesql @query;
```